# Xamarin Android location services - InitializeLocationManager method

Tags: android, google-maps, location, xamarin

I'm trying to implement Location Services into my Xamarin Android app, and i'm having a problem with a specific line of code from the 'get current device location' instruction on the xamarin pages here: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/os_device_resources/gps/get_current_device_location/

One of the methods I need to use is in the following:

```
public class MapFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment, ILocationListener
{

    Location _currentLocation;
    LocationManager _locationManager;
    TextView _locationText;
    TextView _addressText;
    String _locationProvider;

//
//code removed for clarity
//

void InitializeLocationManager()
{
    _locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
    Criteria criteriaForLocationService = new Criteria
                                            {
                                                Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine
                                            };
    IList<string> acceptableLocationProviders = _locationManager.GetProviders(criteriaForLocationService, true);

    if (acceptableLocationProviders.Any())
    {
        _locationProvider = acceptableLocationProviders.First();
    }
    else
    {
        _locationProvider = String.Empty;
    }
}
```

However, the 'GetSystemService(LocationService)' part on the second line of the method is just not recognised (does not exist in the current context error).

I've tried qualifying it with

```
this.Activity.GetSystemService(this.Activity.LocvationService)
```

but then i get the error 'Static member Android.contenxt.context.locationservice cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead'

I'm using Android.support.v4 package if that makes a difference (as it did for Google Map API), and as you can see it's a fragment class.

Can anybody help with this one please?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 _locationManager = (LocationManager)Activity.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService);
```

To explain...

`LocationService` is a static string property defined in `Android.Content.Context` that is used to retrieve an instance of a `LocationManager` in an application. `Activity` subclasses `Android.Content.Context` therefore has the `LocationService` static property available within its class scope.

Fragments however do not subclass Android.Content.Context so doesn't have LocationService defined. Calling `Activity.GetSystemService(LocationService)` is undefined hence the compilation error.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment. I'll give that a go as soon as i can.